# Old home, is this asbestos in the attic?

Tags: insulation, attic

House was built in the 40s and moved in the 70s, no idea if it was reinsulated or not after being moved
[image]

Comment: That looks like loose rock wool insulation, to me. Spend the money on a test kit from your local home center to be certain.

Answer (score 1):

I want to preface my answer with this, you cannot definitively say if there is or is not asbestos in a space through a picture, as it requires a microscope. My assumption is based on research and your initial statement about the age of your home as well as personal experience and research.

That said, chances are high that there would be asbestos in there. However, asbestos undisturbed, isn't dangerous on it's own. It becomes dangerous once you disturb it and it is now airborne. So depending on your plans - this may or may not be cause for worry.

At the end of the day - tests are cheap. I just had some testing done last month. In fact most places offer tests for samples you take yourself (they should provide suggestions for safe handling within the instructions). For my testing it was 50CAD for the first sample, and then an extra 25CAD for each additional sample. The turn around was less than 3 business days.

So if you are really concerned...just get it tested.

Comment: One of the tricks to keeping it from becoming airborne is to handle it wet.

Answer (score -1):

It is *probably* paper waste (or perhaps wool).  Fibrous asbestos like that *was* used for insulation, but usually for high temperature applications rather than domestic roofs.

A quick test is: does it burn when you hold a lighter to it?  If so, it's not asbestos.  If it doesn't burn, it might still be some sort of mineral wool; you will need to get a specialist firm in to test the material.

## WARNING

There is a lot of hysteria about asbestos in domestic buildings, *however* if this  *is* asbestos, then lose fibres like this are **extremely** dangerous.  You will certainly need it removed as quickly as possible, and you may have quite an expensive process to go through before the house is habitable again.  Do not skimp on this; you may not be able to afford it, but you can't afford for you or one of your family to have mesothelioma either.

Comment: It seems like you're admitting there's a lot of hysteria (exaggerated or unfounded concern, typically emotionally charged) and then kind of adding to it.  Asbestos has only a limited threat vector, it has to be aerosolized and you have to breathe the fibers occupationally (like daily for years).

Comment: And asbestos is/was expensive compared to cellulose, mineral wool, fiberglas , etc, so I can't imagine it being used as home insulation. When i scooped pure asbestos out  a 40 lb bag it was grey and looked like bread flower more than anything else ( such as the photo).

Comment: @Harper Fibrous asbestos (like this might be) *is* very dangerous.  People carry that over to stuff like cement board and artex ceilings which are, in the scheme of things, harmless.

Comment: @blacksmith37 - I've seen photos of pipe lagging that looked like that, and https://www.armco.org.uk/asbestos-survey-news/asbestos-insulation-identification/ is similar too.